# TwitterFetch JS mobile text goes off screen.

Tags: javascript, css, mobile

[image]

Hi, I am pretty new to all of this still and am working on making sure that the twitter text link stays within the plate behind it. I am unsure why this happens that it goes over. It works fine on desktop.

Is there something I can do to fix this with CSS? or is it within the JS?

Comment: You can add `word-wrap: break-word;` in the CSS....

Comment: wow, that is the coolest thing! Thank you so much.

Comment: Very welcome :)